# Galera is 3x slower than standalone with durable settings, high CPU idle

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, performance-testing, galera

I am evaluating the Galera Cluster and I can't explain myself the testing results.

When comparing a **single-node** `Galera` with a `standalone MariaDB 10.1.20`, I have noticed a suspiciously big performance difference with durable/non-durable settings:

1. `Galera` is 3x slower than `standalone`, both with durable settings
2. Durable `Galera` is 3x slower than `non-durable Galera`

**Config:**

```
[mysqld]

# durable
sync_binlog=1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1

# non-durable
# sync_binlog=0
# innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2

max_connections=2000

query_cache_type=0
query_cache_size=0

log_bin=1
binlog_format=ROW
log_slave_updates=1

innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4000M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=4
innodb_log_buffer_size=64M

[galera]

wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
innodb-autoinc-lock-mode=2
wsrep_cluster_name=galera
wsrep_node_address=node1
wsrep_node_name=node1
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
wsrep_slave_threads=8
```

**Benchmark: Sysbench 0.5**

```
sysbench \
--test=/usr/share/doc/sysbench/tests/db/oltp.lua \
--mysql-host=localhost \
--mysql-user=root \
--oltp-table-size=1000000 \
--num-threads=128 \
--max-requests=0 \
--max-time=60 run
```

**Results:**

Galera, durable

```
read/write requests: 4994.74 per sec.
```

Standalone, durable

```
read/write requests: 16858.99 per sec.
```

Galera, non-durable

```
read/write requests: 15938.04 per sec.
```

Standalone, non-durable

```
read/write requests: 17055.88 per sec.
```

**Server details:**

```
2 Cores
8 GB RAM
CentOS 7
SSD
```

I have repeated the tests multiple times, even re-bootstrapped the data directory and Galera.

Some observations:

- `CPU idle` (yes, idle) >50% with the durable Galera, <1% in other testing
  scenarios
- `iowait` >20% with the durable Galera, <1% in other testing
  scenarios

Comment: Looks like I am hitting the IOPS limit. But even if this could be the solution, a so much higher IOPS usage doesn't seem to be reasonable.

Comment: This got accepted as a bug: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-11599

Answer (score 2):

`innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1` slows down InnoDB considerably (YMMV).  This is independent of Galera.  `=1` incurs an extra write on every `COMMIT`, explicit or implicit.  This is how it achieves durability even in the face of abrupt power failure.

`=1` is not necessary for Galera -- If a node crashes, rebuild it.

Do not trust a benchmark to judge how *your* application will run.

Other issues -- Did you have a load balancer sharing the writes among the various nodes?  How many nodes?  RAID?  SSD?  Latency between nodes?

And, more importantly, will you ever come close to 16K writes/sec?  If not, then the benchmark provides virtually no clue of how well *your* application will run.

Comment: The problem is, `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1` combined with `sync_binlog=1` seems to slow down Galera *much* more than a standalone MariaDB. All tests were performed on a single node from localhost. The storage is SSD.

Comment: sync_binlog is another thing to turn off in Galera.

Comment: The 'valid' comparison is [ standalone with =1 for both settings ] versus [ Galera with =0 for both ].  Galera will win on robustness (if the nodes don't all go down at the same time -- hence don't put them in the same location); I can't predict on which will perform better (too many variables).